# In Lilypond, silence parts of midi output

Tags: midi, lilypond

I need to engrave a choir piece, where some voices have unpitched parts, like whispered, spoken or screamed words. I want to engrave this using cross-headed notes, like in the following piece of music:

```
\version "2.18.2"

myMusic = {
  \relative c' {
    c4 d e f |
    \override NoteHead.style =#'cross 
    f4 f f f |
    \revert NoteHead.style
    g a b c |
  }
}

\score {
  \myMusic
  \midi {}
}
\score {
  \myMusic
  \layout {}
}
```

As it is annoying to have these parts in the MIDI file with a pitch, I would like the MIDI generator to either ignore them, i.e. replace the notes by corresponding rests, or replace by something unpitched. However, they shall be printed correctly (that's why I have two \score blocks).

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be achieved by using tags (see [the documentation](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/different-editions-from-one-source.html#using-tags)), for example as follows:

```
\version "2.18.2"

myMusic = {
  \relative c' {
    c4 d e f | 
    \tag #'printonly { 
      \override NoteHead.style = #'cross
      f4 f f f |
      \revert NoteHead.style
    }
    \tag #'midionly {
      r4 r r r |
    }
    g a b c |
  }
}

\score {
  \removeWithTag #'printonly
  \myMusic
  \midi {}
}

\score {
  \removeWithTag #'midionly
  \myMusic
  \layout {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*If you want something that makes a percussion type sound in the MIDI file, and is clear to the readers;*

Use a Drum Staff in an Ossia:

```
\version "2.18.2"

myMusic = \new Staff = "main" {
  \relative c' {
    c4 d e f |

    <<
        R1

        \new DrumStaff \with {
                \override StaffSymbol.line-count = #0
                \override BarLine.bar-extent = #'(-1.5 . 1.5) 
                \remove "Time_signature_engraver"
                alignAboveContext = #"main"
                %\magnifyStaff #2/3
                %firstClef = ##f
            } { 
            \drummode {
                hh4 hh4 hh4 hh4 | 
            }
        }
    >>

    g4 a b c |
  }
}

\score {
  \myMusic
  \midi {}
}

\score {
  \myMusic
  \layout {}
}
```

[image: drum staff in an ossia]

Comment: As an amateur singer, I would find this definitely less clear that crossed heads in the staff. It would lead to many time-consuming discussions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want no sound for the unpitched notes, you can put the pitched notes in one `Voice` context and the unpitched notes in another `Voice` context, muting this last one.

```
\version "2.18.2"

myMusic = {
    \relative c' {
        c4 d e f |
        s1 |
        g4 a b c |
    }
}

myMusicUnpitched = {
    \relative c' {
        \override NoteHead.style =#'cross 
        s1 |
        f4 f f f |
        s1 |
    }
}

\score {
    \new Staff { <<
        \new Voice { \myMusic }
        \new Voice { \set midiMaximumVolume = #0 \myMusicUnpitched }
    >> }
    \layout {}
    \midi {
        \context { \Staff \remove "Staff_performer" }
        \context { \Voice \consists "Staff_performer" }
    }
}
```

Sources: 
http://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=438 
http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/controlling-midi-dynamics#overall-midi-volume

By the way, I didn't get what's the point of using two `\score {}` blocks.