# Lilypond: How to tell the midi file not to play the hidden notes?

Tags: midi, lilypond

I noticed that the Frescobaldi midi file produces the hidden notes. How to avoid this?

Comment: You can wrap the hidden note in a tag, followed by a pause of equal length in another tag. The first tag is for printed output, the second for MIDI output. See: https://music.stackexchange.com/q/94781/54798. Another way would be not to use a hidden note but a silent `s` note. It would be easier to help you if you could provide an example.

Comment: It seems odd that you want "notes" that are both hidden _and_ silent, what are you using them for?

Comment: @ Elements in Space: \afterGrace gf2\glissando { \hideNotes af8 \unHideNotes }

Comment: @ jasper : you mean to add an s instead of the note? I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you need to edit your question and add a minimal working example.  Otherwise it's very hard to know how to help you.  https://lilypond.org/tiny-examples.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments I could get the information that this question is about a glissando where the endnote is not printed. Another way not to print notes, apart from `\hideNotes`, would be to use a silent note `s`. However, this cannot be used here, since a glissando to an `s` is not possible and the glissando would instead be printed to the next printed note.

You essentially want the MIDI to be different from what is printed. For this you can use the `\tag` command and create two alternative ways to represent the glissando part, one for the printed matter and another for the MIDI output. You can then even fake the glissando with a row of very short notes.

```
theMusic =
    {
        c'4 c'
        \tag #'glissando { \afterGrace c'2\glissando { \hideNotes c,8 \unHideNotes } }
        \tag #'midigliss { c'32 b a g f e d c b, a, g, f, e, d, c,16 }
        c'4 c'
    }

\score{
    \removeWithTag #'midigliss \theMusic
    \layout{ }
}

\score{
    \removeWithTag #'glissando \theMusic
    \midi{ }
}
```

Printed output:

[image]